# Изменить meta на OCS joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Стало необходимо сменить тайтлы/дескрипшны для магазина,
в зависимости от категорий на joomla 1.5.
head он создает в libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php
Родителя страницы получал таким образом:

```
$cmp = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->parent;
```

и вроде бы все работает, только вход в админку /administrator крашится с 500 ошибкой

Можно как-то обойти этот недуг?

Answer (score 1):

В общем закостылил, в */administrator/index.php* прописал

```
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'helper.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'toolbar.php' );
```

а родителей получал через &  `JFactory::getApplication();`

сделав проверку на админку типа `(strripos($url,'administrator')===false)`